# Microsoft Report Viewer

Tags: .net, vb.net

Need help.  I made a monitoring system that can generate a report using vb.net. I used microsoft report viewer to generate the report, but when I install the system to another PC. I can't generate a report.

This is the error message when I try to make a report.

[image: Error]

Comment: Did you create a deployment project to install the program on the other machine? Did it pick up the ReportViewer as a dependency?

Comment: Yes. i included the rdlc files on the installation.

Comment: Not the rdlc files - they are the reports themselves. In your deployment project, under Detected Dependencies, you should have four Microsoft.ReportViewer files - .Common.dll, .DataVisualization.dll, .ProcessingObjectModel.dll, and .Winforms.dll . If any of these is missing, you will get the error message you report.

Comment: where can I find that files? do I need to put that files together with my system executables?

Comment: On my system they are at eg C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll  However, if you are building a deployment project, these files should be picked up automatically and bound into your .msi file.  If you are planning to deploy manually for some reason, then yes you will need to include these files.

Comment: I checked that directory and the is no \GAC_MSIL. can I download that files somewhere else and put it in my project?

Comment: Check the references for your project itself. On mine it's at c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer . . .

Comment: Ok. found the Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll at the GAC_MSIL and the .common and .winforms at Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\ReportViewer. What do I need is put that 3 files at the project?

Comment: Yes you need the four files as per my second comment above.

Comment: I tried putting the dll files together with the .exe, but still the same result.

Comment: Perhaps you have mismatched versions. If you have the correct set of four then it will work. Note that I listed the .dll files not the xml files etc. Once again, if you build a deployment project these should be picked up automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I've Worked it out by setting the reportviewer dll files to copy to local. Thanks for your effort. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use following link to download crystal report and install in the PC/Server where application is hosted
http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/downloads/redistributables/vs_2008/redist/x86/CRRedist2008_x86.msi

Comment: The assembly that is missing is a microsoft sql reporting service report viewer. Not a crustal reports assembly.